# Column Validation - Simple comparison

Tags: custom-list, validation

I'm attempting something fairly simple but seem to be coming across a few issues.

I have a custom list containing 2 currency fields what I want to do is add validation to the second column so that it can't be greater than the first.

I have gone into the edit column page and attempted to add the formula however I am then presented with below message:

> The formula cannot refer to another column.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or update the formula to reference only this column.

I'm not sure what's causing this but I know it'll be something obvious I'm just not seeing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the correct error message.

If you want to validate between multiple columns, go to the list's property page and click Validation Settings.

```
=[Column 1] > [Column 2]
```